# Retorno null quebrando o código

Tags: java

Quando eu pesquiso certo o nome da pessoa na lista de pessoas ele retorna a pessoa mas quando o retorno é nulo ele quebra o *loop* do código e mostra isso:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at CadastroPessoa.main(CadastroPessoa.java:59) ".

O que fazer para consertar isso?

```
public Pessoa pesquisar(String umNome) {
        for (Pessoa umaPessoa: listaPessoas) {
            if (umaPessoa.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(umNome)) return umaPessoa;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

```
else if (entradaTeclado.equalsIgnoreCase("pesquisar")){

        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer pesquisar:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        //buscando pessoa na lista de pessoas
        Pessoa umaPessoa = umControle.pesquisar(umNome);
        System.out.println(umaPessoa);
        if (!umaPessoa.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("\n******** Pessoa encontrada com sucesso ********\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No if tente colocar

`if (umaPessoa != null)`

Pois deve ser no equals que está quebrando.

Answer (score 2):

Você só pode chamar um método na variável `umaPessoa` se seu valor não for nulo - inclusive `umaPessoa.equals(null)`. A maneira correta de se comparar uma variável com nulo é usando o operador de (des)igualdade (`==` ou `!=`):

```
if ( umaPessoa != null ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`equals` é um método como qualquer outro.

Tal como `x.foo(y)` causa uma excepção quando `x = null`, também `x.equals(y)` o faz.

A forma correcta de verificar se um objecto é nulo é:

```
x == null
```

Portanto, neste caso:

```
if (umaPessoa != null) {
    System.out.println("\n******** Pessoa encontrada com sucesso ********\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Não fica claro pelo sua pergunta qual é a tal da linha 59, mas deduzo que seja a seguinte:

```
if (umaPessoa.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(umNome)) return umaPessoa;
```

Sendo assim você deve, como o amigo @mgibsonbr colocou trocar para a seguinte forma:

```
public Pessoa pesquisar(String umNome) {
        for (Pessoa umaPessoa: listaPessoas) {
            if ( umaPessoa != null ) {
                if (umaPessoa.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(umNome)) return umaPessoa;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

e no outro código, como o amigo @luiscubal colocou

```
else if (entradaTeclado.equalsIgnoreCase("pesquisar")){

        System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa que você quer pesquisar:");
        entradaTeclado = leitorEntrada.readLine();
        String umNome = entradaTeclado;

        //buscando pessoa na lista de pessoas
        Pessoa umaPessoa = umControle.pesquisar(umNome);
        System.out.println(umaPessoa);
        if (umaPessoa != null) {
            System.out.println("\n******** Pessoa encontrada com sucesso ********\n");
        }
```

Comment: De fato, se houver possibilidade da `listaPessoas` ter elementos nulos, então esse teste é necessário. Mas como o OP disse "quando o retorno é nulo" eu e os demais assumimos que a exceção era fora do método.

Comment: A questrão é que ele não mostra o que é a lista né. Se for um ArrayList acho que não teria problema, mas um array comum daria problema.